# Using Git describe without tags

Tags: git

I have a repository that gives me only a hash when I run `git describe`. I did not know until today that it does this because of the `--always` option (which is what I was using) since that repository has no tags. I have another repository with lots of tags.

How can I use `git describe` to exclude tags and just give me a hash? I want to have all of the other functionality of `git describe` in case I need to use the other features, such as dirty marking; I just want to exclude tags. Is this possible, or are tags the central feature of `describe`?

The help page does seem to indicate that, but I just want to be sure. I use this in an Ant build.xml file, so I'm trying to keep this simple.

Comment: If all you want is the hash, then perhaps `git rev-parse HEAD` is more along the lines of what you need...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but it's not necessarily a good idea.  There *is* a `--all` option, which will search *branch* names—or in fact, all references—as well, but if you use that, you might also need `--long`.

#### Description

The central feature of `git describe` output is that it starts with a name that is (or should be) human-readable:

```
v1.2.3
```

To this, Git will, if necessary, add a suffix indicating that the current (or requested) commit is not *quite* the one named by this string.  The suffix tells both you and Git how much to deviate from the tag.  If there is *no* suffix, the tag itself names the commit.  Since tags never<sup>1</sup> move, if we have that name, we are guaranteed<sup>2</sup> to find the correct commit using that name.

With a repository with no tags and no `--always`:

```
$ git describe
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

If we add `--all`, however, we might get this:

```
$ git describe --all
heads/master
```

This *is* a human-readable name, but there is a problem with it: it does not uniquely identify one particular commit, because branch names *do* move.  Once I make a new commit in this repository, `refs/heads/master` now names a *different* commit.

Since the usual *intent* of one of these outputs from `git describe` is to provide a human-readable but exact-commit-specifying ID, a branch name, which is never that exact, is not necessarily a good thing.

You *can* add `--long`:

```
$ git describe --all --long
heads/master-0-g2cbd83f
```

This now uses the `-g...` suffix to specify a prefix of the actual hash ID.  Now Git can verify that `master` itself has not moved, or if it has, you can use the `2cbd83f` string to find the commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, hardly ever.  See [the `git-tag` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_re_tagging) on when and why and why not to move a tag.

<sup>2</sup>Guaranteed to the extent that tags have not moved, anyway.

Comment: I guess maybe git describe isn't the best tool for what I need. What I'm wanting is to include part of the commit hash as part of the version number (build number after version number) so that if a client has an issue, we can tell from their version number what exactly we need to check out to test / duplicate (and I'd still like dirty marking, though maybe not call it "dirty" in the output, maybe just a "-m" suffix). Right now we just rely on the release guy remembering what exact commit he built from, and that's a really bad idea.

Comment: @sorinev: I've used a number of different things for this in the past, and my experience is that the best is: (a) never build anything that goes external from anything "dirty" in the first place; (b) put the actual raw hash ID in as something that can be extracted (especially, extracted automatically on bug reports). If you never build dirty code you can just put the literal output of `git rev-parse HEAD` into a module that simply prints the build hash (said module itself being stored only as a hashless template in the repo). The one flaw is that a private build may not be in the main repo.

Comment: I may end up actually doing a combination of these two methods. I can use the rev-parse for the actual user-visible version number, but then I can have the git describe output in a file that can be retrieved if necessary.

Comment: I've seen things like that, e.g., the template expands out to both the full hash and one or more "human oriented" names.

Answer (score 18):

An easy way to do this is to combine `--always` with the `-exclude` option, using a glob pattern of `*`, to exclude all tags from consideration.  Since it won't find any non-excluded tags, describe will fall back to just the abbreviated sha1 plus optionally "-dirty" and so on.

```
$ git describe --always --dirty --abbrev=5 
2018.02-rc1-58-gca0e6
$ git describe --always --dirty --abbrev=5 --exclude '*'
ca0e6
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since the usual intent of one of these outputs from `git describe` is to provide a human-readable but exact-commit-specifying ID

That is what official `git describe --long` does have to do, according to Git 2.20

See [commit 55f6bce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55f6bce2c9efe7f8a4d2186232aa8227142d9435), [commit 6271d94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6271d94769c4db0a2938761d255a438289561639), [commit c263279](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2632796aa9b042cd6e8c5bbe27c258436dba463) (19 Sep 2018) by [Frederick Eaton (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fb468f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb468f0b1c3b65c01d25e78e612ff54cf2b588e3), 16 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `git-describe.1`: clarify that "human readable" is also git-readable
>
> The caption uses the term "human readable", but the DESCRIPTION did
> not explain this in context.

The [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55f6bce2c9efe7f8a4d2186232aa8227142d9435/Documentation/git-describe.txt#L15-L23) now includes:

> The result is a "human-readable" object name which can also be used to identify the commit to other git commands.

Answer (score 0):

As I did not find any pre-existing "best practice" for automatically naming git revisions where no manual tags have been issued yet, I kind of came up with my own one:

In such a case I manually assign either a tag name "0" or "0.YYYYMMDDzhhmmss" for the initial (oldest) commit in the branch.

I prefer the first variant if I am confident that no one will merge that branch into an unrelated branch, thus producing multiple "initial" commits which need disambiguation.

In the latter case, I prefer the timestamp-based tag name. (The "z" is literal and shall be a hint that this represents a UTC ("zulu") time stamp rather than local time. I chose a lower case "z" rather than an upper case "Z" because the lower-case variant can easier be visually distinguished from the decimal digits sourrounding it because of its different letter height in most fonts.)

Most of the time, however, people just fork a repository and add their own commits on top of this. In this case, there are no multiple initial commits, and a timestamp-based tag name would be overkill. Then a tag name "0" is just fine for the first commit.

Anyway, after manually adding the tag, "git describe --tags" displays something like this

0-12-gb762572

or this

0.202305150z40100-12-gb762572

for the 13th unnamed commit - which looks pretty OK IMO.