# Maven git describe without tags

Tags: maven, git-describe

We're using the Maven plugin `git-commit-id-maven-plugin` and want to make both hash and dirty status available to our build. Our plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

E.g. we have a filtered properties file with:

```
git=${git.commit.id.describe}
```

However this describe-variant cares about tags, which we do not want into our usage of it. If doing this from terminal I see from [other questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816189/2732991) that this is easily done.

E.g. `${git.commit.id.describe}` might return:

```
mytag-hash-dirty
```

Our ideal result would be only:

```
hash-dirty
```

How can I achieve the "hash and dirty status"-only result using the `git-commit-id-maven-plugin` with Maven?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/blob/master/docs/using-the-plugin.md)? Admittedly, I don't know this plugin but it seems you can get what you described above by using `git=${git.commit.id.abbrev}-${git.dirty}`.

Comment: Using `git.dirty` gives `true` or `false`, which in Maven is slightly awkward to translate into either "" or "-dirty". But quite close to the desired result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following configuration of the plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
        <gitDescribe>
            <match>!*</match>
        </gitDescribe>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Where we only include/consider tags that match the `!*` pattern. This works in tandem with `always` being `true` (which happens to be the default). This should be fairly equivalent to the following command:

```
git describe --abbrev=7 --always --match='!*' --dirty
```

This gives the desired result when using the `${git.commit.id.describe}` variable.